# how to retrieve PDF file from database into view using laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-blade, dompdf, laravel-5.8

**Reade Me:**

*Actually document is saved in database successfully but now i want to retrive it as pdf document and show in blade.php page. Drivers are greater than 1 and each driver may has more than 1 documents*

**driverlist.blade.php**

```
<tbody>
 @foreach ($drivers as $driver)
   <tr>
        <td>{{$driver->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$driver->f_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$driver->m_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$driver->l_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$driver->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$driver->document}}</td> ==> here i am getting "null"
   </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**CONTROLLER.PHP**

```
public function driver_list()
{
    // dd("driver_list");
    $drivers = Driver::all();
    return view('admin/driverlist', compact('drivers'));
}
```

**Logic while saving document**

```
if ($file = $request->file('document'))
    {
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/assets/docs/drivers');
        $file->move($destinationPath, $name);
        $driver->document= $name;
    }
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `document` column in database?

Comment: i have used "string" datatype in database

Answer (score 0):

You can use any laravel pdf generator packages like: mpdf, dompdf ...